# Why is my user info on Chatify for Laravel no loading?

Tags: laravel

I have something interesting going on in my Laravel app that I cannot seem to fix.  I am using Chatify (https://chatify.munafio.com) and it's not working quite right.  Here is what is happening....

In the route, there is this line:

```
Route::get('/{id}', 'MessagesController@index')->name('user');
```

My controller looks like so:

```
public function show($id)
{

    $data = Acct::where('id', '=', $id)->with('gallery')->with('reviews')->with('painter')->first();
    return view('public', [
        
        'button_link' => '/chatify/'.$data->id,
        
    ]);
}
```

The link on the page looks like this:

```
<a href="{{ $button_link }}"><button class="btn btn-success mx-auto text-center m-2 w-75">{{ $button_text }}</button></a>
```

When I click that link it takes me to the correct Chatify view (https://www.example.com/chatify/65), but the users info does not load.

However, if I manually enter the same url (https://www.example.com/chatify/65) and press enter, the user's info comes up just fine.

Does anybody know why this would be happening?

Comment: Anything in console or network tab?

Comment: @Mihai yes.  "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.example.com/chatify/getContacts' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."  I've done some reading on this (CORS) and am reading that there is a solution in Laravel 8 middleware.  What I don't know is how to implement the solution.  Still somewhat new to Laravel...

Answer (score 1):

Go to file "config/database.php"
and change
'strict' => true,
TO
'strict' => false,
after save
run console
"php artisan config:cache"